# Error Cannot read property 'token' of undefined in Vue JS when I run my code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-apollo

I am working on Django and Vue js using GraphQL and Vuex store to communicate between my frontend and my backend.

When I send a request from my frontend, I get a 200 OK response from my backend but on my frontend, I get an error titled

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined.

Here is an overview of my code starting from

1. vuex configurations used to interact with my server.

```
    // The apolloClient Trigger
    
    import { apolloClient } from '../../apollo'
    
    import {USER_ID, AUTH_TOKEN } from '../../constants/settings'
    
    // The User Authentication mutation and queries
    
    import {SIGNIN_USER_MUTATION} from "../../graph/auth/mutation"
    
    const state =  {
        token:null,
        userId:"",
        errorMsg:"",
        authStatus: false,
      }
      
    const getters = {
        isAuthenticated: state => !!state.userId,
        authStatus: state => state.authStatus
      }
    
    const mutations =  {
    
      SET_TOKEN(state, token){
            state.token = token,
          state.authStatus = true
        },
    
    
      SET_USER_ID(state, userId){
          state.userId = userId
        },
    
      ERR_TOKEN(state, err){
    
          state.errorMsg = err
        }
      }
    
    
    const actions  =  {
    
      // The user login API
    
        async userLogin({commit}, authDetails){
    
    
            try{
              const response = await apolloClient.mutate({ 
                mutation: SIGNIN_USER_MUTATION, 
                variables: { ...authDetails } 
            
            });
            const token = JSON.stringify(response.tokenAuth.token)
            const userId = JSON.stringify(response.tokenAuth.user.id)
            console.log(token)
    
            commit('SET_TOKEN', token)
            commit ('SET_USER_ID', userId)
    
            localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token)
            localStorage.setItem(USER_ID, userId)
    
            }
    
            catch(e){
    
              console.log(e)
            }
        },
      }
    
    
      export default {
    
        state,
        getters,
        mutations,
        actions,
    
      }
```

2. Finally here is the login.vue component where I make the call.

```
<template>
  

<div class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">



  <div class="max-w-md w-full space-y-8 rounded-lg bg-white px-8 py-8 shadow-md">
    <div>
      <img class="mx-auto h-12 w-auto" src="/img/area.svg" alt="Workflow">
      <h2 class="font-body mt-6 text-center text-xl tracking-wider text-gray-900">
        Sign in to your account
      </h2>
    
    </div>
    <form class="mt-8 space-y-6">


      <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true">
      <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm space-y-8">
        <div>
          <label for="email-address" class="font-body text-gray-900 tracking-wider">Email address</label>
          <input v-model = "authDetails.email"  id="email-address" name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email" required class="mt-3 appearance-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="password" class="font-body tracking-wider text-gray-900">Password</label>
          <input v-model = "authDetails.password" id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" required class="mt-3 appearance-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm" placeholder="Password" >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <input id="remember_me" name="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded">
          <label for="remember_me" class="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900 font-body tracking-wider">
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="text-sm">
          <a href="#" class="font-body font-medium text-gray-600 tracking-wider hover:text-green-600">
            Forgot your password?
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button v-on:click.prevent="loginUser()" type="submit" class="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm rounded-md text-white font-body tracking-widest bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500"  >
          <span class="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
            <!-- Heroicon name: lock-closed -->
            <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-white group-hover:text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          </span>
          Sign in
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>

     
  </div>


</div>

      

</template>

<script>

import { mapActions } from 'vuex'


export default {

 data(){

  return{

      authDetails:{

        email:"",
        password:"",
      }

        }
 },
methods:{

  ...mapActions(['userLogin']),

  loginUser:function(){
      this.userLogin(this.authDetails).then(() => this.$router.push('/feeds')
        
        )

  }

}

}
</script>
```

3. Here is the error I get when I open my console.

```
3auth.js?c7d4:76 TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
    at _callee$ (auth.js?c7d4:62)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
```

Comment: What does the response from the API look like? Either from the dev console or from `console.log(response)` before the `const token = ...` line.

Comment: Might also be helpful to know what `apolloClient.mutate` looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, thanks to everyone who has contributed to this, and finally I get my answers.

I made a mistake when referencing the data from the backend, it was supposed to be this way

```
 const token =   JSON.stringify(response.data.tokenAuth.token)
  const userId =  JSON.stringify(response.data.tokenAuth.user.id)
```